# How to undo a "Reset Toolbox" in VS2008?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, toolbox

Is there any way to "un-Reset" the Toolbox in Visual Studio 2008?

I was trying to get my first-ever WPF UserControl to appear in the Toolbox. I rebuilt my project, then right-clicked on the Toolbox and chose "Reset Toolbox" from the pop-up menu; hoping that would "refresh" the control list (I know better now). Alas, the reset removed ALL the controls from the Toolbox for WPF projects (It's still OK for Win-Forms projects).

So is there a relatively quick way to restore all "the standard WPF controls" to the Toolbox?... I only had the standard controls (being a WPF noob) so "No" I didn't take a backup before I hit the reset switch... BIG Sigh!

Thanking you all in advance,

Keith.

---

**EDIT:** To document my (sort of) resolution to the problem...

I got my WPF controls back, but they're not in there nice seperate toolboxes (i.e. the expandable sections, or whatever you call them). Meh! It'll have to do ;-)

To get them back... With a WPF Window open (Window1.xaml for example): right-click on the General "toolbox", select "Choose items ..." from the pop-up menu, goto the "WPF Components" tab, select ALL items and click the checkbox of the last item (to make all tools visible), then click the OK button... then (if you want) right-click on the toolbox and select "Sort Items Alphabetically" then go back into right-click-Toolbox ~ Choose Items ~ WPF Components; and untick all those items which don't have distinctive icon *(the "default icon" is a white window with a blue border containing a "cone" which appears to be blowing red bubbles... stoners beware?!?!)*. You'll probably have to OK your "unticks" half-way down the list, coz you can't scroll the toolbox (too see the icons) whilst the Choose Items dialogue is open.

Cheers all. Hope this helps the next MS Victim.

Keith.

PS: For what it's worth, I still think this is a "bug" in VS2008... Resetting the toolbars should retore them to there original condition. Which, as far as I'm concerned, includes the "out of the box" WPF toolbox configuration. I presume it's lost them coz the WPF Toolbox's where/are a "tack on"... implemented as "custom" toolboxs (the same as a user-defined toolbox). Sigh.

If it's still a "bug" in VS2010 then maybe it should be reported, so that atleast it (probably) won't be propagated to 2012, or whatever comes next.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running this command in VS2008 Command Prompt-

```
del "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\*.tbd"
```

Refer to this link - http://msmvps.com/blogs/coad/archive/2010/05/07/reset-the-visual-studio-toolbox.aspx

As per this it will re-populate the data.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas RV, There were NO `*.tbd` files in my `C:\Documents and Settings\corlettk\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0` directory to delete... I looked in both Windows-Explorer, and the command-prompt (in case Explorer was hiding them as "system-files"). Before you ask, yes I am a local-admistrator on my XP-SP3 box... so nothing (I think) is hidden from me.

Comment: However, i can see files in my system and you are right those are hidden files. I looked in command prompt (dir /a:h) and can see 4 tbd files over there.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bit late now, but I find if I change environment settings etc and want to get them back I open a 2nd copy of Visual Studio before I close the other Visual Studio instance. Then close the one you changed and then immediately close the 2nd version.

This normally persists your settings from the last instance closed for next time opening.